# How can I make the BackColor of a Label update faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, backcolor

*EDIT:*

*I have managed a workaround. Now on `MouseEnter`, I set the focus to the button, and I change the `MouseOverBackColor` to the button's current `BackColor`; I also have an event handler (in the parent container of the button) for `GotFocus` that changes the `BackColor` accordingly. I have NO idea why this works this way but I have only gotten it to work in this particular combination. Again, I am looking for better ways to do it so keep it up with the answers.*

I made a Button override and the Text property now overrides to a custom child Label. The problem is I have styles applied to the button (color changing on focus/mouse enter).

I would like the Label to change it's color accordingly and I have achieved this in two ways so far:

1. Set the label's `BackColor` to `Transparent`
2. Override the `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseLeave` to also change the Label's `BackColor` accordingly.

They both work; the only problem is there is a slight delay when changing the `BackColor` of the Label; this result to a little tearing in graphics when the Button's `BackColor` changes.
This isn't such a big deal but it is a little annoying; would appreciate any useful advice you would bestow upon me.

Comment: Why don't you just set the BackColor of the label to transparent **permanently**?

Comment: @Daniel: I doubt that will help performance. The question doesn't seem to indicate that (s)he is changing the label's `BackColor` to anything *else* in between.

Comment: You are right, the question doesn't indicate it. But that's the only way, I can explain a delay in BOTH scenarios...

Comment: It sounds like from your question that you're displaying a `Label` control **on top of** a `Button` control. If so, why in the world are you doing this? You can just change the `BackColor` property of the `Button` and achieve the same effect.

Comment: The problem is that I also have `MouseEnterBackColor` and `MouseDownBackColor` (which are independent from `BackColor`) and they need to be set dynamically to inherit the parents' `Backcolor`, which can also change (focused or not) and when that scenario occurs (`MouseOver`, then change `MouseEnterBackColor` to parent's `BackColor`, that is when the chopiness of the label's `BackColor` occurs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

depending upon how frequently your application processes the windows message pump or how idle it is, you may need to call Control.Update() to force .NET to update the painting of the control immediately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.update.aspx

Comment: Since i have posted this question, i did learn a lot of things, concerning among others this particular issue. Looking back to this question it doesn't really make as much sense now as it did back then :) Even so, you are right; if I am not happy with the flow rate of the message pump, enforce what I need.